# Endless waiting while changing route in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I'm working on a Vue.js webapp. Recently I realized then when I want to change route (going home) from a Vuex action, it takes a lot of time and never end. It take 4600 MB RAM and 70% CPU.
Here is the indicted code:

```
impostaSelezionabili: ({ commit,dispatch }, payload) => {
    commit("associazioniSelezionabiliImpostate", payload)

    const prefe = payload.prefe
    
    if (payload.associazioni.length == 1) {
        commit("associazioneScelta", payload.associazioni[0].codAssociazione)
        dispatch("toolbarManager/setToolbarVisibility", true, {root: true})
        router.push({ path: '/' })
    }

},
```

Everything works perfectly without `router` line, when I add `router.push({ path: '/' })` it gets the problem.

Is there a way to solve?

---

Router config / Routes:

```
export const router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        { path: '/', component: HomePage, name: "Home", meta: "Home" },
        { path: '/servizi', component: ServiziPage, meta: "Servizi" },
        { path: '/servizi/:id', component: ServizioPage, meta: "Servizi" },

        { path: '/login', component: LoginForm},

        { path: '/corsi', component: Corsi, meta: "Corsi" },
        { path: '/corsidisponibili', component: Corsi, meta: "Corsi disponibili" },

        // otherwise redirect to home
        { path: '*', redirect: '/', meta: "Home" }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Did you test `router.push` by its name instead of `path` ?

Comment: @NargesPms nothing changes...

Comment: Please provide your router config and routes in your question too.

Comment: Now you can check the question, I've added router config and routes

Comment: @NargesPms Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your router exists and that is not an import of `vue-router`. You need to use the `router` that you constructed with the `new Router()`.

But I think that is the best way to solve it - that navigating inside a component after a Promise returned by that action will be resolved because in the current case your action isn`t pure.